# Salesforce - Populate text are from drop down selection

Tags: salesforce

I have a picklist with three values and a text area that has three values as well, but I would like to correlate one value from the picklist with one value of the text area. Any thoughts as on how I can do this?

Comment: it's not totally clear what you're trying to achieve here: is the idea that a user selects a value from the picklist, and this populates the text area? In what context is this happening-- visualforce page?

Comment: Yes, user picks a drop down and I want to populate test area. This is from a time based workflow, wanted to show some text based on selected option before the workflow was kicked off.No this is not Visual Force but I am looking into that as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creating a visualforce page is an option, you can do this with a controller extension, or a custom controller. For example, you could override the save() method and have your new save code populate the text for you-- simply create a map of dropdown values to text area content and set the text as desired. It should also be possible to do this without saving by using some of the visualforce built in AJAX hooks: look at the onchange attribute. (Note that last I checked the onchange did not fire properly for lookups, but it may work for dropdowns)

Have a look at the visualforce documentation here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm